# Split String and Do Calculation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string

Let's say I have given data as string:

```
+----------+
|Size      |
+----------+
|15X10     |
|5X4       |
|3         |
|2X6X5     |
+----------+
```

I want to write this column as integer like this:

```
 +----------+
 |Size      |
 +----------+
 |150       |
 |20        |
 |3         |
 |60        |
 +----------+
```

Some of them are multiply of three numbers, some of them just one number. I can split the string but cannot make MySQL to calculate the number. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest query ever, but you can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html):

```
SELECT
  Size,
  CASE
    WHEN Size LIKE '%X%X%' THEN
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(Size, 'X', 1)*
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Size, 'X', 2), 'X', -1)*
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Size, 'X', 3), 'X', -1)
    WHEN Size LIKE '%X%' THEN
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(Size, 'X', 1)*
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Size, 'X', 2), 'X', -1)
    ELSE Size
  END AS multipied_size
FROM
  sizes
```

this query will work only if you have up to two X. Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/260d3/2).