# Mysql Split String and Select with results

Tags: mysql, string, select, split

I have currently 2 tables looking like this:

```
frontend_users:
uid | usergroup | name
1   | 1,2,3     | Michael
2   | 2         | Tobias
3   | 1         | Colin
...
```

and

```
usergroups:
uid | title
1   | member
2   | reporter
3   | admin
```

I tried to split the usergroup and select for each number the usergroup and add it to the result of the display, which should look like this in the best case:

```
uid | name    | groups
1   | Michael | member, reporter, admin
2   | Tobias  | reporter
3   | Colin   | member
```

The best result I found so far was from here:
[Split String and Do Calculation in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735762/split-string-and-do-calculation-in-mysql)
but I can't seem to be able to select from the other table with the substring_index result.
My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT frontend_users.uid, frontend_users.name
CASE
    WHEN frontend_users.usergroup LIKE '%,%,%' THEN
        CONCAT((SELECT usergroups.title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(frontend_users.usergroup, ',', 1)),
            (SELECT usergroups.title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(frontend_users.usergroup, ',', 2), ',', -1)),
            (SELECT usergroups.title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(frontend_users.usergroup, ',', 3), ',', -1)))       
    WHEN frontend_users.usergroup LIKE '%,%' THEN
        CONCAT((SELECT usergroups.title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(frontend_users.usergroup, ',', 1)),
            (SELECT usergroups.title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(frontend_users.usergroup, ',', 2), ',', -1))),
    ELSE (SELECT usergroups.title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = frontend_users.usergroup)
END AS groups
FROM frontend_users, usergroups
```

I tried to use a for loop for the number of groups but the results were even worse.

Any hints how I can use the select query with the substring_index result?

Comment: Bad DB design , you should normalize it and never store comma-separated data for relational attributes.

Comment: It fails **first normal form**

Comment: sadly I can't change this, since it was predefined and is used like this in the whole cms.

Comment: @StifanCral Instead of working at db side, it is a little bit easy to work on coding side

Comment: I'd love to do that, but the request was to display it db side instead of the backend, which isn't exactly my field of expertise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about the normalization. However for the current schema consider the following

```
mysql> select * from frontend_users ;
+------+-----------+---------+
| uid  | usergroup | name    |
+------+-----------+---------+
|    1 | 1,2,3     | Michael |
|    2 | 2         | Tobias  |
|    3 | 1         | Colin   |
+------+-----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from usergroup ;
+------+----------+
| uid  | title    |
+------+----------+
|    1 | member   |
|    2 | reporter |
|    3 | admin    |
+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To get the desired result you may use the following query which is not efficient for long run

```
select 
u.uid,
u.name, 
group_concat(g.title) as groups 
from frontend_users u 
join usergroup g on find_in_set(g.uid,u.usergroup) > 0 
group by u.uid ;

+------+---------+-----------------------+
| uid  | name    | groups                |
+------+---------+-----------------------+
|    1 | Michael | admin,reporter,member |
|    2 | Tobias  | reporter              |
|    3 | Colin   | member                |
+------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Now a better approach would be to create an association table as

```
mysql> create table user_to_group (uid int, gid int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> insert into user_to_group values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And a better query would be

```
select 
u.uid,
u.name, 
group_concat(g.title) as groups 
from frontend_users u 
join user_to_group ug on ug.uid = u.uid 
join usergroup g on g.uid = ug.gid 
group by u.uid ;

+------+---------+-----------------------+
| uid  | name    | groups                |
+------+---------+-----------------------+
|    1 | Michael | member,admin,reporter |
|    2 | Tobias  | reporter              |
|    3 | Colin   | member                |
+------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working perfectly, also thanks a lot for the advice of normalization

Answer (score 0):

Abhik Chakraborty answers is better solution, but i just fix your last code, if you want.

you can check it at [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eea47/1)

```
SELECT frontend_users.uid, frontend_users.name,
CASE
    WHEN usergroup LIKE '%,%,%' THEN
        CONCAT(
           (
             SELECT title FROM usergroups
             WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(usergroup, ',', 1), ',', -1)
           )
          ,',',
           (
              SELECT title FROM usergroups
              WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(usergroup, ',', 2), ',', -1)
            )
          ,',',
           (
              SELECT title FROM usergroups
              WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(usergroup, ',', 3), ',', -1)
            )
          )
    WHEN usergroup LIKE '%,%' THEN
        CONCAT(
           (
             SELECT title FROM usergroups
             WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(usergroup, ',', 1), ',', -1)
           )
          ,',',
           (
              SELECT title FROM usergroups, frontend_users
              WHERE usergroups.uid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(usergroup, ',', 2), ',', -1) Limit 1
            )
          )
    ELSE
        (SELECT title FROM usergroups, frontend_users WHERE usergroups.uid = usergroup Limit 1)
END AS groups
FROM frontend_users
```