# MySQL Select from column use ^ as delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql

My question similar to [MySQL Split String and Select with results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071597/mysql-split-string-and-select-with-results). Currently I have 2 tables:

**`student`**

```
uid | subject_id | name
1   | 1^2^3^4    | a
2   | 2^3^       | b
3   | 1          | c
```

**`subject`**

```
uid | subject_name
1   | math
2   | science
3   | languange
4   | sport
```

The result I expected is:

```
uid | name    | subject_passed
1   | a       | math, science, languange, sport
2   | b       | science, languange
3   | c       | sport
```

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT
student.uid,
student.name, 
group_concat(subject.subject_name) as subjects_passed 
from student 
join subject on find_in_set(subject.uid,student.subject_id ) > 0
group by student.uid
```

Which returns the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'join subject on find_in_set(subject.uid,student.subject_id ) > 0
>   group' at line 7

I believe because of [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). According to documentation, this function expects `,` as delimiter. Is there any alternative query I might use ?

Comment: Well the *best* thing to do is to not store multiple value in a single column and use a junction `[uid|single_subject_id]` table instead

Comment: patrick you really need to change this schema to a junction one. wanna see it ? Yours violates third normal form (3NF) design patterns. Then again you said in other comments that you have a lot of data, so I doubt you would even do it based on inertia :>

Comment: Yes, currently what I trying to do is enhance it, might try recommendation by Abhik, table design is not designed by me >_<..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) the separator:

```sql
SELECT
    student.uid,
    student.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(subject.subject_name) AS subjects_passed
FROM student
JOIN subject ON FIND_IN_SET(subject.uid, REPLACE(student.subject_id, '^', ',')) > 0
GROUP BY student.uid
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/270b8/1)

---

If you decide to de-normalize your tables it is fairly straight forward to create the junction table and generate the data:

```
-- Sample table structure
CREATE TABLE student_subject (
    student_id int NOT NULL,
    subject_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, subject_id)
);

-- Sample query to denormalize student <-> subject relationship
SELECT
    student.uid AS student_id,
    subject.uid AS subject_id
FROM student
JOIN subject ON FIND_IN_SET(subject.uid, REPLACE(student.subject_id, '^', ',')) > 0
```

```
+------------+------------+
| student_id | subject_id |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          1 |
|          1 |          2 |
|          1 |          3 |
|          1 |          4 |
|          2 |          2 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          3 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the update. So I export the query result to csv format, and store back to the new table.. awesome..

Comment: No, export to CSV only to see if data looks OK. Then use an [`INSERT...SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) query.

Comment: Hi again, i tried run this query,
"select
st.uid,
st.name,
group_concat(sb.subject_name) as passed_subject
from student st
join student_subject ss on ss.stid = st.uid
join subject sb on sb.uid = ss.subid
where st = studentID --(IN parameter from stored procedure)
group by st.uid;"
but it took longer time compare to 'replace' solution, any idea ?
student_subject(3.5M rows), subject(1.5K rows), student(700k)

Comment: 3.5M rows is too many, you must to define indexes on the `student_subject` table. If possible, create a composite primary key `(stid, subid)` so that no student can be joined to the same subject twice. If this is not possible then create an index on the same. Also create the same index in reverse i.e. `(subid, stid)`. Let MySQL choose the best one. BTW 1.5k subjects look too much to me.

Comment: can say merge from few school, each have their subject code and name. imagine whole database contains the information of students in one city, thats where 1.5k subjects came from. kind of redundant and messy.

Answer (score 3):

You should never store data with a delimiter separator and should normalize the table and create the 3rd table to store student to subject relation.

However in the current case you may do it as

```
select
st.uid,
st.name,
group_concat(sb.subject_name) as subject_name
from student st
left join subject sb on find_in_set(sb.uid,replace(st.subject_id,'^',',')) > 0
group by st.uid
```

Here is the option to create third table and store the relation

```
create table student_to_subject (id int primary key auto_increment, stid int, subid int);
insert into student_to_subject(stid,subid) values
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1);
```

Now you can remove the column `subject_id` from the `student` table
So the query becomes

```
select
st.uid,
st.name,
group_concat(sb.subject_name) as passed_subject
from student st
join student_to_subject sts on sts.stid = st.uid
join subject sb on sb.uid = sts.subid
group by st.uid;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f02df

Comment: why in the world would anyone downvote this answer ?!

Comment: @DrewPierce someone got really pi** with my answer :-)

Comment: @SalmanA yes I realized once I posted the answer ! However I always choose not to provide any duplicate answer. And close the duplicate answer no matter how easy the answer is :)

Comment: @SalmanA, I'm a sock puppet eh? `Definition: a false online identity, typically created by a person or group in order to promote their own opinions or views.` Ok, if you think so.

Comment: Hi abhik, thank you for the recomendation, currently the student table has quite a number of data, is there any way to populate / insertion  the third table automatically based on previous 2 tables ?

Comment: That would be fairly difficult if not impossible using pure sql, you can however write a script to do the job in the application level.

Answer (score 2):

Think you can replace `^`with `,` before calling find_in_set:

```
SELECT
student.uid,
student.name, 
group_concat(subject.subject_name) as subjects_passed 
from student 
join subject on find_in_set(subject.uid, replace(student.subject_id,'^',',') ) > 0
group by student.uid
```

But of course storeing values in such a format is very bad db design.